# Jmeter JSR223 Function calls from several threads

Tags: jmeter

I have written a function in file BeanShellFunction.bshrc called XYZ which I can use it in several of my BeanShell (pre and post) samplers throughout threads and .jmx files and all over the map.

Now I like to do the same in JSR223 (pre and post) and clearly I cant call that XYZ function because thats for pre and post Bean files (or Java).  How do I do the same and write a fucntion called ABC for my pre/post JSR223 functions which I can use in any thread and any .jmx file?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use some custom Groovy code in [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) you need to "tell" JMeter your Groovy file location via a property, i.e. add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
groovy.utilities=/path/to/your/file.groovy
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up

---

For other JSR223 friends you can add [Script.evaluate()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Script.html#evaluate-java.io.File-) function to the beginning of your [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) like:

```
evaluate(new File('/path/to/your/file.groovy'))
```

After that you will be able to use the functions from your file.

Also be aware that if your class is in compiled form and under [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) you don't even need to take any extra actions.

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)